# Unable to Set Firestore Rules for Firestore Native Database in a GCP Project with Default Database in Datastore Mode

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, terraform

I have a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project where I operate multiple Firestore databases. The default database is in Datastore mode, and I have an additional database in Firestore Native mode. I'm trying to set security rules for the Firestore Native database, but I'm facing challenges:

When I use the Firebase Console, I get an error indicating that the project is set up to use Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode and that this mode can only be accessed from the Google Cloud Console.

[image: Firebase Firestore Screenshot]

In the Google Cloud Console, I can view the Firestore rules, but there's no option to edit them.

I tried using Terraform to deploy the rules. While Terraform indicates that the rules have been applied successfully, the rules in the Google Cloud Console remain unchanged.

When attempting to use the Firebase CLI, I receive an error stating that the Firebase CLI can only manage projects using Cloud Firestore in Native mode.
Here's the error from the Firebase CLI:

> Error: It looks like this project is using Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode. The Firebase CLI can only manage projects using Cloud Firestore in Native mode.

**Firestore Rules I try to apply for testing my frontend**

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if true;
    }
}
```

**Firestore Rules displayed in my GCP Console**
[image]

**Terraform code**

```
resource "google_project_service" "firestore" {
    project = local.project
    service = "firestore.googleapis.com"
}

resource "google_firestore_database" "database" {    
    project                           = local.project
    name                              = "name of the database"
    location_id                       = local.location
    type                              = "FIRESTORE_NATIVE"
    concurrency_mode                  = "PESSIMISTIC"
    app_engine_integration_mode       = "DISABLED"
    #point_in_time_recovery_enablement = "POINT_IN_TIME_RECOVERY_ENABLED"
    depends_on = [google_project_service.firestore]
}

resource "google_firebaserules_release" "primary" {
    name         = "cloud.firestore"
    ruleset_name = "projects/${local.project}/rulesets/${google_firebaserules_ruleset.firestore.name}"
    project      = local.project

    lifecycle {
      replace_triggered_by = [
        google_firebaserules_ruleset.firestore
      ]
    }
  }

resource "google_firebaserules_ruleset" "firestore" {
    source {
      files {
        content = file("firestore.rules")
        name    = "firestore.rules"
      }
  }

  project = local.project
}
```

I cannot separate this into different GCP projects because I run integration services in this project, and one of the services uses Firebase primarily. I need to add a frontend on top of this service to view some Firestore documents.

Has anyone faced a similar issue, and is there a workaround to set Firestore rules for the Firestore Native database in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

The Firebase console has not yet been updated for projects with multiple databases. You're hitting a particularly hairy edge-case as Datastore mode is unlikely to be ever supported in Firebase.

That pretty much leaves setting the rules through the API (or CLI?) as the only option.